# Jquery new Date return wrong result

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using mvc 4. When I use bellow code in script

```
new Date(2012, 12, 16, 03, 20, 00)
```

it return as

```
Wed Jan 16 2013 03:20:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Please help me, I am not able to understand why does this happen, it should return

```
Sun Dec 16 2012 03:20:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Months are 0 based. When you pass it 12, it's essential month "13", which Javascript will interpret as January of the *next* year.

So to get the date you want, the code would be `new Date(2012,`**`11`**`, 16, 03, 20, 00)`